# Package installation failed: npm ERR! code ERESOLVEnpm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'node' as it is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, npm-install

```
Mohameds-MacBook-Air:client sakeeljawfer$ ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.0.
✔ Package information loaded.
✖ Package installation failed: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'node' as it is null.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sakeeljawfer/.npm/_logs/2021-04-16T03_41_10_925Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

> this is the /Users/sakeeljawfer/.npm/_logs/2021-04-16T03_41_10_925Z-debug.log file that includes the versions and dependencies

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.0',
0 verbose cli   '--quiet'
0 verbose cli ]
```

> _logs/2021-04-16T03_41_10_925Z-debug.log thus the error log file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it this way:

`npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

In https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started go to "Manual installation" and follow the instructions :)